# Script doesn't work when accessed from other page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a site in JQuery / JQuery Mobile. I'm testing pages one by one. I created a page that asks a user for input and does a autocomplete with records from the database (PHP/MySQL). It works just as I wanted.

But, when I go to my index page and then follow the link to the new page, it doesn't work anymore. Someone told me something about that JQuery Mobile looks at all the pages as if they are one big page and it is therefore that additional scripts are not loaded later on.

Does this sound familiar and where can I find more documentation on this? How should I solve this? Create one big JavaScript file and have all pages call the functions from the main file?

Autocomplete page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple, remote</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
</style>

<script>

$(function()
{
    $("#brands")
        .autocomplete
            ({  
                source: 'getbrands.php',
                minLength:2,
            });

    $("#collection")
        .autocomplete
            ({
                source: 'getcollection.php',
                minLength:2,
            });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
Enter your Brand:
<input type="text" id="brands" />

<br />
    Enter your Collection:
<input type="text" id="collection" />

<br />

<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

index page:

```
<?php
   include_once('inc/checkloginfirst.inc.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Web</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/validate.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Beta</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
        <li><a href="m-search.php"><center>Quick Search </center></a></li>
        <li><a href="m-browse.php"><center>Browse </center></a></li>
        <li><a href="brandsearch-test.html"><center>Add new </center></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><center>User Settings</center></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="m-index.php" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <a href="m-logout.php" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" style="float: right;">Logout</a>            
 </div>
 </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Gabrie

Comment: Sorry about that, did an edit to include the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed correct.  For scripts to work if you pull them in you must include them within the `<body>` of the page being pulling in via AJAX.  The `<head>` is totally ignored by the AJAX-loading.

If you want to initialize functions within that script make sure you bind to the `onload` method of the body tag of that page or bind to `pageinit` e.g.

```
...
    <body onload="initializePreviousReports()">
        <div data-role="page" id="options" data-theme="a">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).bind('pageinit', initializePreviousReports());
                function initializePreviousReports() {
                    // Some logic here.
                }
            </script>
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>Previous Reports</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div id="previousReportContainer" data-role="content">Put some content in here.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
...
```

Hope that helps. R.

Comment: Thank you. What would be better in the long run or more convenient, place all scripts in one central javascript file as much as possible or still put them on the page they're being used and use the onload / pageinit fucntion.

Comment: @Gabrie, If there's not a big chance of the page being loaded/visited, then keep the javascript on that page as it will help reduce initial load-times and data-usage for the main and other pages but if you feel that it will be visited regularly I recommend you load it in a central file. Note that if there is a chance that this page will get visited without users first going to your main/entry page then your page won't render correctly if you're not loading the framework in every page `<head>`.  In such a case you should load all javascript (framework and custom) in the `<head>` of every page.